# Determine if all characters in a string are unique in C++

Tags: c++

Trying to implement a fairly simple program in C++. I'm kinda new to this language. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

bool isUnique(string);

int main(){
    bool uniq;
    string a;
    cout << "Please input a string, not a very long one...."<< endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    uniq = isUnique(a);
    if (uniq == true)
        {
            cout << "The string has no repeatations." <<endl;
        }else{
            cout << "The characters in the string are not unique." <<endl;
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}

bool isUnique(string str){

int len = strlen(str);
bool uniq = true;

for (int i = 0; i <= len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= len; ++j)
        {
            if (str[j] == str[i])
            {
                uniq = false;
            }
        }
    }
return uniq;
```

}

The program compiles but has some logical errors I suppose. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you give example for an error ?

Comment: You're going to have to learn how to debug code. I'm really wondering why you're making more work for yourself and copying the string to an array instead of just using the string, though.

Comment: You should explain what goes wrong, and what the input is. But there are at least one direct fault in your code: `int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);` should probably be `int len = strlen(arr);`. However, it is completely unnecessary to copy the string in the first place. You could just use `str[i]` and `str[j]` where you use `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` now.

Comment: IF I use the strlen(str) directly I get..... uniq.cpp:28:12: error: no matching function for call to 'strlen'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a string, so it is not necessary to convert it to a char array. Use the string to check. You can check it like this:

```cpp
bool isUnique(string str){

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        {
         if(i < str.size()-1){                                             
            for (std::string::size_type j = i+1; j < str.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (str[j] == str[i])
                {
                    uniq = false;
                }
            }
         }
        }
    return uniq;
}
```

Comment: This code runs, but I fail to understand a few things. When I modify this code to size_t len = strlen(arr) it doesnt work. Can you throw some light on that.

Comment: strlen(arr) doesn't work because strlen except a char pointer and you know use a string. To determine the lenght of a string use the method size(). Like this int len = str.size().

Answer (score 6):

An simple criterion for uniqueness is that there are no repeated characters in the sorted range of characters. There are [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in the standard library for this:

```
#include <algorithm>  // for std::sort, std::unique
#include <iostream>   // for std::cin, std::cout
#include <string>     // for std:getline, std::string

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Please input a string, not a very long one: ";
    std::getline(input, std::cin);

    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    bool u = std::unique(input.begin(), input.end()) == input.end();

    if (u) { std::cout << "Every character is unique.\n"; }
    else   { std::cout << "The string contains repeated characters.\n"; }
}
```

As an optimization, you can exit early if the string has more characters than there are unique characters, though you'd need some way to determine what that number is.

Comment: By far the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check uniqueness much easier without a nested loop: make an array of `bool[256]`, cast `char` to `unsigned char`, and use as an index into the array. If a `bool` has been set, the characters are not unique; otherwise, they are unique.

```
bool seen[256];
for (int i = 0 ; i != str.length() ; i++) {
    unsigned char index = (unsigned char)str[i];
    if (seen[index]) return false;
    seen[index] = true;
}
return true;
```

The idea is simple: you mark characters that you've seen as you go, returning `false` if you see a "marked" character. If you reach the end without returning, all characters are unique.

This algorithm is O(n); your algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>). This does not make much difference, though, because it is impossible to construct a string of unique characters that is longer than 256 characters.

Comment: "because it is impossible to construct a string of unique characters that is longer than 256 characters" why is that?

Comment: @DallaRosa For the same reason it's impossible to have a group of 367 people where 2 of them don't have a birthday on the same day.

Comment: @DallaRosa: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: @jrok and Krizz well if you start from the assumption that you only have 256 pigenholes, than yes. Actually that was the point of my question all along, because if you consider the existence of unicode, which by the way, is pretty much standard nowadays, unless you're doing Programming 101 in the 90's, you have _way_ more than 256. This answer only valid if you put a big disclaimer saying it's only valid for ASCII characters. And then again, if we go this way, just include the visibile characters in the array cause the control characters for example don't need to be there either.

Comment: @DallaRosa UNICODE does not play a slightest bit into this question, though, because `char` simply cannot fit more than 256 values. One could use `wchar` and `wstring`, but that would make it a different question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I get what you mean. However the question doesn't really talk about data types, only about characters in a string. Being raised to a language that uses diacritics and after living and working Asia for almost 10 years, you don't expect ASCII characters as your most probable input. So probably I'd suggest a solution that can support unicode.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many errors in your code. For example instead of

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
```

there shall be

```
size_t len = std::strlen( arr );
```

Or instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= len; ++i)
```

there shall be at least

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
```

and so on.

And there is no any need to define a character array. Class `std::string` has all that is required to do the task.

Try the following function

```
bool isUnique( const std::string &s )
{
    bool unique = true;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size() && unique; i++ )
    {
        std::string::size_type j = 0;
        while ( j < i && s[j] != s[i] ) ++j;

        unique = j == i;
    }

    return unique;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool isUnique( const std::string &s )
{
    bool unique = true;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size() && unique; i++ )
    {
        std::string::size_type j = 0;
        while ( j < i && s[j] != s[i] ) ++j;

        unique = j == i;
    }

    return unique;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "abcdef" );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isUnique( s ) << std::endl;

    s = "abcdefa";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isUnique( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with the errors fixed:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isUnique(string,int); //extra parameter

int main(){
    bool uniq;
    string a;
    cout << "Please input a string, not a very long one...."<< endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    uniq = isUnique(a,a.length()); //pass length of a
    if (uniq == true)
        {
            cout << "The string has no repeatations." <<endl;
        }else{
            cout << "The characters in the string are not unique." <<endl;
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}

bool isUnique(string str,int len){

    bool uniq = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; ++i) //len-1 else j would access unitialized memory location in the last iteration
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < len; ++j) //j<len because array index starts from 0
            {
                if (str[j] == str[i])
                {
                    uniq = false;
                }
            }
        }
    return uniq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
int main () {


    bool uniqe=false;
    string a;
    char arr[1024];
    int count[256]={0};
    cout << "Please input a string, not a very long one...."<< endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    strcpy(arr, a.c_str());
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
      count[(int)(arr[i])]++;      // counting the occurence of character
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
     if(count[i]>1){       // if count > 1 means character are repeated.
         uniqe=false;
       break;
     }else{
        uniqe=true;

     }
    }
   if(uniqe)
      cout << "The string has no repeatations." <<endl;
    else
      cout << "The characters in the string are not unique." <<endl;


    return 0;
}
```